# Querying MySQL via stored procedure performing slow

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a input file with roughy 200,000 lines and I need to query MySQL database (engine : InnoDB) for each of the line. I read one line from file at a time and make my target variable/field. Then I query MySQL database with that target field. The information I need is not located in a single table rather several tables with more than 100 million rows in them. Hence, I made a function to query the database. I make all the necessary queries inside the function and retrun the concatenation of the queries as text via the funciton. But it is not performing fast. Is there any way to speed this procedure or Shall I completely follow some other approach? I have checked the queries with explain command and they are fine. Some smart solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you could, I would load that file into a table and then have a single query that returns the results you are looking for.  Otherwise looping through 200,000 lines and running 200,000 queries will pretty much always be time consuming.

Comment: show the queries and their execution plans.